# Change group access to directory and all sub directories and files

Tags: command-line, permissions

There is **root ownership** and **root group** applied to `/media/pandya/Ext4/*` ("pandya" is user-name). To apply group "pandya" I run following command:

```
 sudo chown -hR root:pandya /media/pandya/Ext4/*
```

Now, There is **root ownership** and **"pandya" group** applied to `/media/pandya/Ext4` ***and all sub files and directories.***

But group "pandya" has only permission "Access files" (for directories) and "Read Files" (for files) for all sub directories and files.

So, **How to apply full permissions** ("create and delete files" to directories and "read and write" to files) **to group "pandya"** ? So-that I can fully access `/media/pandya/Ext4/`
*and all sub directories and folders* with "pandya" group.

Comment: I changed your edit. You don't want to blindly make all files executable. To give write access, just use `chmod g+w`. To make all subfolders accessible, you will need to add the executable bit to them but you cna do so (for directories only) using `find /media/pandya/Ext4/ -type d -exec chmod g+x {} +`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `chown` command is to change user and group *ownership*, to change permissions, you need `chmod`. So, once you have set the group ownership to `pandya` using `chown` as you have, change the permissions to give the group write access:

```
chmod -R g+w /media/pandya/Ext4/
```

From `man chmod`:

> The format of a symbolic mode is  [ugoa...][[+-=][perms...]...],  where
>          perms  is  either zero or more letters from the set rwxXst, or a single
>          letter from the set ugo.  Multiple symbolic modes can be  given,  separated by commas.
>
> A  combination  of the letters ugoa controls which users' access to the
>          file will be changed: the user who owns it  (u),  **other  users  in  the
>          file's group (g)**, other users not in the file's group (o), or all users
>          (a).  If none of these are given, the effect is as if a were given, but
>          bits that are set in the umask are not affected.
>
> The  operator  +  causes the selected file mode bits to be added to the
>          existing file mode bits of each file; - causes them to be removed;  and
>          =  causes  them  to  be added and causes unmentioned bits to be removed
>
> -R, --recursive
>
> change files and directories recursively

So, `g+w` means "give users that belong to the file's group write access" and `-R` means apply to all files and subdirectories recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sudo chown -hR pandya:pandya /media/pandya/Ext4/
```

For more information, run `man chown` in terminal for the man file.

---

**EDIT:** By the way, you don't need the * at the end since you're doing it recursively.

Comment: Can Permission to Group pandya not be changed?

Comment: That does not affect the permissions. Presumably the OP _wants_ the files to be owned by `root`.